# Spark Caching won't work for specific RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have one RDD that is not being cached. I set for it the default `cache()` directive, and used `count()` to force an action.

The `is_cached` method returns `True`, but in Spark UI I can't see the RDD in the storage tab (and further calling `count` takes the exact same time as the first time).

`toDebugString` returns:

> (4) RDD CoalescedRDD[8] at coalesce at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 [Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]\n |  MapPartitionsRDD[7] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 [Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]\n |  s3://... HadoopRDD[6] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 [Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]'

And `StorageLevel`:

```
StorageLevel(False, True, False, False, 1)
```

The Input data is 64MB and I have 2 executors with 500MB remaining in each. Other RDDs are cached just fine.

Code:
*before coalescing numPartitions is 5943

```
RDD = sc.textFile('s3:/...',use_unicode=False).coalesce(4)
RDD.cache()
RDD.count()
```

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible code sample

Answer (score 0):

Cached memory you can see in executor tab in spark UI. For same time on memory and disc, that is because just one operation on rdd/df is going to take same time as it needs on io for both.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but what I meant is that the RDD won't show up in there ( with all the other cached RDDs)